# setTag и PopupMenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

Вообщем есть PopupMenu с обработчиком

```
int i = 1;
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx,v);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu,popup.getMenu());
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
            return true;
        }
```

Как можно int i протащить внутрь. Хотел через тєги, но похоже нельзя.

Comment: например, создать `Map<MenuItem, Integer>`, в который записать соответствие `MenuItem`'a нужному интеджеру

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы использовать во внутреннем классе переменные, они должны быть:

- финальными (`final int i = 1;`)

или

- они должны быть определены на уровне класса, содержащего внутренний класс. Т.е., например, анонимный обработчик нажатий может обращаться к полю активити или фрагмента, в коем этот обработчик повешен.